# Call a java class from a kotlin activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am working on a project on Android Studio. I have the main activity inside a kotlin file (MainActivity.kt) and from it I am trying to call a static method(start_netClient()) from inside a java file (dists.java) via an Intent object by putting this listener for my *bbutton* inside the onCreate() of the MainActivity :

```
        bbutton.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(view: View): Unit {
            // Handler code here.
            val intent = Intent(this, Net_Activity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    })
```

The Net_Activity and its content:

```
class Net_Activity: AppCompatActivity() {

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    dists.start_netClient()
}
}
```

What I get for this code during the build is this error on Intent on the MainActivity.kt:

```
Error:(65, 30) None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public constructor Intent(p0: Context!, p1: Class<*>!) defined in android.content.Intent
public constructor Intent(p0: String!, p1: Uri!) defined in android.content.Intent
```

I am relatively new to the whole Android thing, but what is it that I am missing, and how is it possible to connect a java method and a kotlin class via the Intent? Is it best effort to use two Activities or is there a different approach?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in your `Net_Activity`? Why does it have that function `main(args: Array<String>)`?

Comment: I am trying to call the start_netClient() method from the dists class, which is a java class.

Comment: And umm, you sure that's all the content inside the `Net_Activity`?

Comment: I have the imports above the Activity declaration, I have inserted it inside the AndroidManifest, yet it is all clear. Is there something that I should have included inside that matches with the Intent construction error?

Answer (score 6):

It seems that when you use `this`, you're referencing the listener object (`View.OnClickListener`) rather than your activity. You should be able to fix this by using `this@Net_Activity`, which references your activity instead of the listener. The full line should look like so:

```
val intent = Intent(this@Net_Activity, Net_Activity::class.java)
```

When you declare an object in Kotlin (via the `object` keyword) you're defining an anonymous class, and then creating a single instance of this class. This allows you to override methods for things like listeners, but as you've discovered, it means you have to double check your uses of `this`.

Comment: I added the line as: val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, Net_Activity::class.java).
The way you prompted to I got an unresolved reference for Net_Activity. 
(The declaration of the intent val is inside the MainActivity, not the Net_Activity.)
Is this way of thinking even correct, as the Net_Activity is a kotlin activity and not a java class?

Comment: Ah, I thought your code was within `Net_Activity` - that should be correct.